# Cocos2D How To Change First Responder Class

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch

During my game i transition from one scene to another. In my second scene I don't have the option to say:

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

So when i touch the screen it does not call:

```
- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

My question is how do i get the ccTouchBegan function to work in my new scene?

Comment: the same way as in the first scene. isTouchEnabled is a CCLayer property, not CCScene

Comment: I i had it has a CCScene works great now, Thanks.